# Nginx run mod_wsgi, always core dump

Tags: nginx, mod-wsgi, coredump

I have installed mod_wsgi for nginx, and configure the nginx.conf:

```
location / {
    wsgi_pass /home/matthew/Documents/mod_wsgi/examples/nginx-echo.py;
}
```

But it always core dump, even I run the example in the mod_wsgi source code.

```
2015/07/21 23:15:25 [notice] 859#0: signal process started
2015/07/21 23:15:29 [alert] 32595#0: worker process 860 exited on signal 11 (core dumped)
```

I am not sure where goes wrong.

Comment: If you really are talking about the very old and no longer maintained mod_wsgi module for nginx, then don't use it. The design of it within nginx has problems. Read http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/05/blocking-requests-and-nginx-version-of.html If you are going to use nginx, either use uWSGI behind it and use uwsgi_ass, or proxy using HTTP to gunicorn or Apache/mod_wsgi (mod_wsgi-express).

Comment: Helpful, Thank you again @GrahamDumpleton